# How to remember users that donated to remove ads?

Tags: uwp

I added ads to my Windows UWP app, but the next step is I want to add in app purchase for donations.  If the user donates I want to remove the ads.  However how do you do this in such a way that remembers the user donated?  For example if they reinstall the app, or use another device the app should remember that this user donated money to remove ads.

Is there a best practice for this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The in-app purchases API has methods to check if an in-app has been purchased.

Comment: Is it this -  AddOnLicenses property of the StoreAppLicense object?

Comment: take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/enable-in-app-product-purchases

Comment: Also which type of add on should I use for donations (set up in dev center) -  durable, developer managed consumable, or store managed consumable?  I'm thinking its a consumable so they can repurchase as many times as they want.  Is that right?  Not really sure which one though.

Comment: Yes, consumable

Answer (score 1):

There is a very help sample that shows how to code in-app purchases and then check if the user has purchased a particular license. It's at: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Licensing-API-Sample-19712f1a.

Using the license check, you can hide the ads in your app. This license check is on the LicenseInformation class. Calling LicenseInformation.ProductLicenses["DonationMade"].IsActive will give that information.

This license is per user regardless of device, so it gives you the functionality that you are asking for.